# For an infinite set $S$ , is $|S| < |$Sym $(S) |$?

Tags: set-theory

Let $S$ be an infinite set ; does there exist any surjection of $S$ onto $A(S)$ ( the set of all bijections on $S$ ) ? I have atmost been able to prove that if $C( S)$ is the set of all countable subsets of $S$  then there is an injection from $C(S)$ to $A(S)$ . Please help , thanks in advance .

Comment: I think Cantor's diagonal argument can be used to prove that $A(\mathbb N)$ is not countable.

Comment: I am pretty sure that I answered at least once that $|A(S)|=2^{|S|}$.

Answer (score 1):

For an Infinite set X of any Cardinality, |sym(X)|  = |P(X)|, and so |sym(X)|  > |X|

Lemma: a function f: Y -> Z is equivalent to a subset of Y x Z. The function associates a unique value in Z with a value in Y, and the collection of these pairings is a subset of all possible pairings of Y x Z (there are many pairings that are not functions where y in Y is paired with more than one z in Z). The collection of pairings that represent a function is therefore a member of P(Y x Z), the power set of Y x Z.
It follows that the set of all functions {f|f: Y ->  Z} is a subset of P(Y x Z) and 
therefore |{f}| ≤ |P(Y x Z)|.

Proof:
We show in two steps that |sym(X)|  ≤ |P(X)| and |P(X)|  ≤  |sym(X)|  and hence their equality.

Any permutation in sym(X) is a bijection from X -> X and therefore a function, so that sym(X) is a subset of all functions from X -> X, and therefore a subset of P(X x X). Hence, 
|sym(X)|  ≤ |P(X x X)|. But |X x X| = |X|, and therefore |P(X x X)| = |P(X)| so that 
|sym(X)|  ≤ |P(X)|

The set X can be represented as the union of two disjoint sets X_1 and X_2 of the same cardinality as X. There is therefore a bijection between then, say f. We can define a mapping g: P(X_1) -> sym(X) as follows:
For A ∈ P(X_1), p ∈ sym(X) is the permutation 
a ∈ A (⊂ X_1) exchanges with  f(a) ∈ X_2 and b  ∈ X_1\A -> b (stays unchanged).
Then g is an injection from P(X_1) into sym(X), so that | P(X_1)| ≤ |sym(X)|. But again, |X_1 | = |X|, so that | P(X_1)| = | P(X)| and thus |P(X)| ≤ |sym(X)|.

Comment: Corrected typo to say |sym(X)| > |X|